# Updating Java from 1.7.0_201 to latest version and getting an error

Tags: java, jenkins

I am trying to update my Java from 1.7.0_201 to latest version and I am getting the following error no matter what I do:

```
invoke-rc.d: initscript jenkins, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package jenkins (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jenkins
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: How about posting the relevant portion of your init file or the cmd invoked? Can you run java -version OK?

Comment: vagrant@web:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_201"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.17) (7u211-2.6.17-0ubuntu0.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.201-b00, mixed mode)

Comment: ya i am able run java version.

Comment: This the following error i have been getting for installing jenkins:    
vagrant@web:~$ sudo apt install jenkins
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Answer (score 1):

First never go the the latest version of Java if you want to use Jenkins. Use always the recommeded Java Version of Jenkins :

Modern Jenkins versions have the following [Java requirements](https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/java/):

```
Java 8 runtime environments, both 32-bit and 64-bit versions are supported

Since Jenkins 2.164 and 2.164.1 [1], Java 11 runtime environments are supported

    Running Jenkins with Java 11 is documented here

    There are some precautions to take when upgrading from Java 8 to Java 11 in Jenkins, please follow these guidelines.

Older versions of Java are not supported

Java 9 and Java 10 are not supported

Java 12 is not supported
```

So first upgrade to Java 8 that is the recommended version of Jenkins. Instead of going of the latest.